# Fetching data from Facebook Ads API with Google Apps Script

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

I need to fetch some data from Facebook Ads API. I already accomplished  the extraction of it, with daily and aggregated views separately and that’s where my problem begins.

When I fetch reach (for example) by date the sum of each day inflates the total number (you can see that by comparing the codes bellow) and if I tried to call 2 separate URLs the system won’t know how to deal with it.

---

1st - This API call breakes the data by day and if I sum the reach by day I get the result **27,982**
    **https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_xxxxx/insights?fields=reach,frequency&level=Ad&time_range[since]=2019-02-11&time_range[until]=2019-03-11&time_increment=1**

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "reach": "2048",
          "frequency": "1.007813",
          "date_start": "2019-02-14",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-14"
        },
        {
          "reach": "2195",
          "frequency": "1.018679",
          "date_start": "2019-02-15",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-15"
        },
        {
          "reach": "413",
          "frequency": "1",
          "date_start": "2019-02-15",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-15"
        },
        {
          "reach": "2777",
          "frequency": "1.008282",
          "date_start": "2019-02-16",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-16"
        },
        {
          "reach": "1012",
          "frequency": "1.008893",
          "date_start": "2019-02-16",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-16"
        },
        {
          "reach": "2683",
          "frequency": "1.006336",
          "date_start": "2019-02-17",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-17"
        },
        {
          "reach": "1000",
          "frequency": "1.009",
          "date_start": "2019-02-17",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-17"
        },
        {
          "reach": "2650",
          "frequency": "1.013585",
          "date_start": "2019-02-18",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-18"
        },
        {
          "reach": "990",
          "frequency": "1.012121",
          "date_start": "2019-02-18",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-18"
        },
        {
          "reach": "2228",
          "frequency": "1.010772",
          "date_start": "2019-02-19",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-19"
        },
        {
          "reach": "928",
          "frequency": "1.009698",
          "date_start": "2019-02-19",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-19"
        },
        {
          "reach": "2253",
          "frequency": "1.006214",
          "date_start": "2019-02-20",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-20"
        },
        {
          "reach": "946",
          "frequency": "1.013742",
          "date_start": "2019-02-20",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-20"
        },
        {
          "reach": "2117",
          "frequency": "1.00992",
          "date_start": "2019-02-21",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-21"
        },
        {
          "reach": "881",
          "frequency": "1.00454",
          "date_start": "2019-02-21",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-21"
        },
        {
          "reach": "1811",
          "frequency": "1.006626",
          "date_start": "2019-02-22",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-22"
        },
        {
          "reach": "230",
          "frequency": "1",
          "date_start": "2019-02-22",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-22"
        },
        {
          "reach": "820",
          "frequency": "1.00122",
          "date_start": "2019-02-23",
          "date_stop": "2019-02-23"
        }
      ],
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "MAZDZD",
          "after": "MTcZD"
        }
      }
    }
```

2nd - This API call don't break reach by any dimension and I get the result **24,295** (what it's almost 3,000 less then the first result)
** https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_xxx/insights?fields=reach,frequency**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "reach": "24295",
      "frequency": "1.162503",
      "date_start": "2019-02-14",
      "date_stop": "2019-02-23"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MAZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Every metric that has a deduplication process (like reach) when broken down by any dimension like day or campaign will inflate the total (aggregated) number.

Does anybody knows how I solve this?

Best,

Anna

Comment: The date ranges seem to be totally different, so not sure why different sums should actually come as a surprise here?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, just fixed on problem description. Messed up on copy/paste.